# UDP Server Socket Buffer Overflow

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, buffer

I am writing a C++ application on Linux.  My application has a UDP server which sends data to clients on some events.  The UDP server also receives some feedback/acknowledgement back from the clients.

To implement this application I used a single UDP Socket(e.g. `int fdSocket`) to send and receive data from all the clients.  I bound this socked to port 8080 and have set the socket into NON_BLOCKING mode.

I created two threads.  In one thread I wait for some event to happen, if an event occurs then I use the fdsocket to send data to all the clients(in a for loop).

In the another thread I use the `fdSocket` to receive data from clients (`recvfrom()`).  This thread is scheduled to run every 4 seconds  (i.e. every 4 seconds it will call `recvfrom()` to retrieve the data from the socket buffer.  Since it is in NON-BLOCKING mode the `recvfrom()` function will return immediately if no UDP data is available, then I will go to sleep for 4 secs).

The UDP Feedback/Acknowledge from all the clients has a fixed payload whose size is 20bytes.

Now I have two questions related to this implementation:

1. Is it correct to use the same socket for sending/receiving UDP data
   with Mulitiple clients ?
2. How to find the maximum number of UDP Feedback/Acknowledge Packets my application can handling without UDP Socket Buffer Overflow (since I am reading at every 4secs, if I
   receive lot of packets within this 4 seconds I might loose some packet ie., I need to find the rate in packets/sec I can handle safely)?

I tried to get the Linux Socket Buffer size for my socket (`fdsocket`) using the function call `getsockopt(fdsocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF,(void *)&n, &m);`.  From this function I discover that my Socket Buffer size is 110592.  But I am not clear as what data will be stored in this socket buffer: will it store only the UDP Payload or Entire UDP Packet or event the Entire Ethernet Packet? I referred this [link](http://www.6test.edu.cn/~lujx/linux_networking/index.html?page=0131777203_ch04lev1sec1.html) to get some idea but got confused.

Currently my code it little bit dirty , I will clean and  post it soon here.

The following are the links I have referred before posting this question.

1. [Linux Networking](http://www.6test.edu.cn/~lujx/linux_networking/index.html?page=0131777203_ch04lev1sec1.html)
2. [UDP SentTo and Recvfrom Max Buffer Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292281/udp-sendto-and-recvfrom-max-buffer-size)
3. [UDP Socket Buffer Overflow Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027758/udp-socket-buffer-overflow-detection)
4. [UDP broadcast and unicast through the same socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800302/udp-broadcast-and-unicast-through-the-same-socket?rq=1)
5. [Sending from the same UDP socket in multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460645/sending-from-the-same-udp-socket-in-multiple-threads?rq=1)
6. [How to flush Input Buffer of an UDP Socket in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299894/how-to-flush-input-buffer-of-an-udp-socket-in-c?rq=1)
7. [How to find the socket buffer size of linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865069/how-to-find-the-socket-buffer-size-of-linux?rq=1)
8. [How do I get amount of queued data for UDP socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278189/how-do-i-get-amount-of-queued-data-for-udp-socket?rq=1)

Comment: Why only every 4 seconds? Why not just have that thread sit in a `select()` call waiting for data?

Comment: @Collin Since UDP is not reliable we have implemented the following mechanism.  For every UDP packet sent to a client I expect a acknowledgement packet (a simple UDP packet with a fixed string.) back from the client. If I didn't get the acknowledgement packet from a client then I will again resend the packet after 4 seconds

Comment: Ok, but with that setup the server is going to think packets are lost even when they're not. What happens when a packet is sent just after the client has read the socket? With network timings, the server will think there was never a response even though there was. There's still no reason not to respond right away. Instead of rolling your own reliability though you might look at using TCP or something like: http://udt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You should either use select() or use blocking mode and set a 4-second SO_TIMEOUT. That way if a packet arrives within the 4 seconds you will read it immediately, instead of wasting time in the sleep.

Comment: @EJP .  Your comment is great, it gives clear idea to me, I will try to implement that way.  I want to vote your comment up, but unfortunately I have clicked it twice, the system is not allowing me to vote your comment :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having socket reading at fixed interval of four seconds definitely sets you up for losing packets. The conventional tried-and-true approach to non-blocking I/O is the de-multiplexer system calls [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html)/[`poll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html)/[`epoll(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html). See if you can use these to capture/react to your other events.

On the other hand, since you are already using threads, you can just do blocking [recv(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html) without that four second sleep.

Read [Stevens](http://books.google.com/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA207#v=onepage&q&f=false) for explanation of `SO_RCVBUF`.

Comment: along with this the comment posted by [EJP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) gives a clear idea.

Answer (score 5):

You can see the maximum allowed buffer size:

```
sysctl net.core.rmem_max
```

You can set the maximum buffer size you can use by:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608
```

You can also set the buffer size at run-time (not exceeding the max above) by using setsockopt  and changing SO_RCVBUF. You can see the buffer level by looking at /proc/net/udp.

The buffer is used to store the UDP header and application data, rest belong to lower levels.

Answer (score 4):

Q: Is it correct to use the same socket for sending/receiving UDP data with Mulitiple clients ?

A: Yes, it is correct.

Q: How to find the maximum number of UDP Feedback/Acknowledge Packets my application can handling without UDP Socket Buffer Overflow (since I am reading at every 4secs, if I receive lot of packets within this 4secs I might loose some packet ie., I need to find the rate : noofpackets/sec I can handle safely)?

A: The bottleneck might be the network bandwidth, or CPU, or memory. You could simply do a testing, using a client which sends ACK to the server with consecutive number, and verify whether there is packet loss at the server.